# ArcGIS Server: "MapServer is not supported with the current license."

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, c#, arcgis-server

I am at a complete loss... I have a Server 10.0 license on my machine but the following code fails:

```
if (ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Server) == false)
    throw new Exception("License Failed");

MapServerClass mapServer = new MapServerClass();
mapServer.Connect(pathToMap); // Fails!
```

`ComException was unhandled`

`MapServer is not supported with the current license.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out immediately after asking this... funny how that works.

**Solution:**

```
IAoInitialize aoInit = new AoInitializeClass();
aoInit.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer);
```